# update sql table with increment number

Tags: sql

I have a table of information in sql, I have added a counter field to it, we want to fill this field based on the item field in order. Of course, the item field is variable and must have its own counter based on each type.

```
|item|no|
|:---|-:|
|110 |  |
|120 |  |
|110 |  |
|150 |  |
```

After the update

```
|item|no |
|:---|--:|
|110 | 1 |
|120 | 1 |
|110 | 2 |
|150 | 1 |
```

ok.

Comment: A `ROW_NUMBER()`, `PARTITION BY item`

Comment: (1) Tag the question with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* tables.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`.  Assuming that you have a column that specifies ordering:

```
select t.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by item order by <ordering col>) as number
from t;
```

Note:  If you don't care about the ordering, you can use `order by item`.  Some databases allow `row_number()` without the `order by` as well.

Comment: Looks like OP wants to perform a `count(item) GROUP BY item;`